# Vector usage in jdk1.8

Tags: vector

What does this line do in jdk 1.8 version?

```
import java.util.Vector;//is this still used

static Vector<Boolean>isprime = new Vector<>(1000001);
```

I wrote it outside main inside class and when called its size it showed 0. Doesn't it be a vector of 1000001 elements each initialised with true by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

First of all, `Vector` is obsolete and you should use `ArrayList`.

Secondly, the argument you pass is not the initial `size` of the list, but it's `capacity`, which represents the amount of items you can add before it needs to resize its internal storage.